# IIS 7.5 does not write NLog (maybe due to permissions)?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, nlog

I have my webserver (IIS 7.5) on windows server 2008 R2. The Nlog on my server does not write any log files. To resolve the issue I have tried

1. Full rights to the log directory for NLog
2. Switched off IE enhanced Security

I can see that my AppPool is started in task manager - processes with the DefaultAppPool user. I have tried everything I know and can't understand what could be wrong. Please help.

Comment: Please, show me source of NLog.config.

Comment: For me, Nlog not write in folder with name "folder-name". Works fine with "foldername".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was entirely different. I found via dependency walker that some windows DLLs were missing from my machine

Comment: which dlls you were missing?

Comment: @fantastory This is quite sometime ago. I think it was MSVCR71.dll

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the troubleshooting steps listed here:

https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

I have found that `<nlog throwExceptions="true">` in particular usually provides quite a lot to work with.

Comment: where we can inspect nlog thrown exceptions?